# How to transform a flat table dataframe into a dataframe with nested arrays

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
|Activity_A1|Activity_A2|Agreement_A1|Agreement_A2|    Line_A1|    Line_A2|
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| Act1_Attr1| Act1_Attr2|  Agr1_Attr1|  Agr1_Attr2|Line1_Attr1|Line1_Attr2|
| Act1_Attr1| Act1_Attr2|  Agr1_Attr1|  Agr1_Attr2|Line2_Attr1|Line2_Attr2|
| Act1_Attr1| Act1_Attr2|  Agr2_Attr1|  Agr2_Attr2|Line3_Attr1|Line3_Attr2|
| Act2_Attr1| Act2_Attr2|  Agr3_Attr1|  Agr3_Attr2|Line4_Attr1|Line4_Attr2|
| Act2_Attr1| Act2_Attr2|  Agr3_Attr1|  Agr3_Attr2|Line5_Attr1|Line5_Attr2|
| Act2_Attr1| Act2_Attr2|  Agr4_Attr1|  Agr4_Attr2|Line6_Attr1|Line6_Attr2|
| Act3_Attr1| Act3_Attr2|  Agr5_Attr1|  Agr5_Attr2|Line7_Attr1|Line7_Attr2|
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

I need to transform it into a dataframe with nested arrays. An array of lines should be grouped within agreement. An array of agreements should be grouped within activity. The result should be like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Activity_A1|Activity_A2|                                                                                                                                       Details|
+-----------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Act1_Attr1| Act1_Attr2|  [[Agr1_Attr1, Agr1_Attr2, [[Line1_Attr1, Line1_Attr2], [Line2_Attr1, Line2_Attr2]]], [Agr2_Attr1, Agr2_Attr2, [[Line3_Attr1, Line3_Attr2]]]]|
| Act2_Attr1| Act2_Attr2|  [[Agr3_Attr1, Agr3_Attr2, [[Line4_Attr1, Line4_Attr2], [Line5_Attr1, Line5_Attr2]]], [Agr4_Attr1, Agr4_Attr2, [[Line6_Attr1, Line6_Attr2]]]]|
| Act3_Attr1| Act3_Attr2|                                                                                      [[Agr5_Attr1, Agr5_Attr2, [[Line7_Attr1, Line7_Attr2]]]]|
+-----------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is there any way to do this in scala?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like that :

```scala
val dfWithArray = df.groupBy($"Activity_A1", $"Activity_A2", $"Agreement_A1", $"Agreement_A1")
    .agg(collect_set(array($"Line_A1", $"Line_A2")).as("Details"))
    .groupBy($"Activity_A1", $"Activity_A2")
    .agg(collect_set(struct($"Agreement_A1", $"Agreement_A2", $"Details")).as("Details"))
```

[Collect_set](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) is removing duplicates. If you want to collect duplicates, just use collect_list instead.

Comment: There is an error in the second GroupBy because input to function array should all be the same type. Changed it to struct and it worked well. Thank you!
The final code is 
`val dfWithArray = df.groupBy($"Activity_A1", $"Activity_A2", $"Agreement_A1", $"Agreement_A2")
 .agg(collect_set(array($"Line_A1", $"Line_A2")).as("Details"))
 .groupBy($"Activity_A1", $"Activity_A2")
 .agg(collect_set(struct($"Agreement_A1", $"Agreement_A2", $"Details")).as("Details"))`